# Is it possible to JSON patch a Map element in Spring Data REST?

Tags: spring-data-rest

I have a user entity with a list of settings. Originally I used List but using Map returns a JSON that is easier to search.

**List version:**

Database column declaration in entity:

```
private List<Setting> settings = new ArrayList<>();
```

Rendered JSON on GET:

```
"settings": [
    {"name1" : "setting 1", "value" : 5},
    {"name2" : "setting 2", "value" : 6},
]
```

JSON-patch:

```
[{"op":"replace","path":"/settings/0/value", "value": "6"}]
```

**Map version:**

Database column declaration in entity:

```
@MapKey(name = "name")
private Map<String, Setting> settings = new HashMap<>();
```

Rendered JSON on GET:

```
"settings": {
    "name1": {"name1" : "setting 1", "value" : 5},
    "name2": {"name2" : "setting 2", "value" : 6},
}
```

How to patch this? Tried this, but it is not working. Jackson wants a property named `name1` in my POJO.

```
[{"op":"replace","path":"/settings/name1/value", "value": "6"}]
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to add/remove a new setting from the list? Is `Setting` another entity with its own repository?

Comment: I want to change the value for the setting with the map key 'name1', IOW I want to address an element in a Map by its key instead of addressing it by index in a List. Yes, `Setting` is another entity, but it does not have a repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you prefer having `settings` field as `Map`, here is one way you could implement it:

```java
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@MapKeyColumn(name = "settings_name")
@Column(name = "settings_value")
@CollectionTable(name = "entity_settings", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "entity"))
private final Map<String, String> settings = new HashMap<>();
```

Now to add or replace a setting, all you need to do is a PATCH call on the entity endpoint `PATCH /entity/id` with a JSON object in request body:

```json
Content-Type: application/json
PATCH /entity/id
{
  "settings": {
     "name1": "5"
  }
}
```

Above request would create a new setting with key `name` and value `5` if it doesn't exist already else replace the value.

I would argue `Setting` need not be an entity and can be completely owned by the containing entity. Unless you want `Setting` to be accessible on its own but as you said in comments it doesn't have its own repository, I assume that's not the case.